# Text column unique case insensitive

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have text column which has to be unique, but case insensitive. However I have to store text in original form (I can't transform it to lower/upper case). Is it possible in Postgres? Or I have to store two columns - one with original text and one (with unique index) transformed to lower case for example?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a functional index with either an upper or lower function.

eg.

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON table USING btree (lower(column_name));`